# How do I call and decode a JSON web service from PHP?

Tags: php, json

From within PHP, how can I call an external JSON web service and then decode the returned string?

For example (pseudo-code):

```
<?php

$var jsonStr = json_decode("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false");

?>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you almost had it!

```
<?php
$jsonObject = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false"));
?>
```

Comment: obviously this is a v simple implementation with no error checking or anything really, but it answers the question

Answer (score 0):

Nathan has it. You may want to explore [the curl library](http://php.net/curl) for a more robust HTTP request approach, too.